# Meteor mocha watch mode displays lines of code instead of assertion messages

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js

I am using `practicalmeteor:mocha` in watch mode and have written some UI tests (unit testing Template-components).

I have the weird issue, that my failed tests do not reveal the assertion message but a code snippet instead.

I have attached an image with an example output:

[image]

Unfortunately I did not find any information about a configuration related to this in the documentation of the package or mocha itself.

My test command is the following:

```
meteor test --driver-package practical meteor:mocha
```

The test code is the following:

```js
// PACKAGES
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {Template} from 'meteor/templating';
import {$} from 'meteor/jquery';
import {Random} from 'meteor/random';
import {chai, assert} from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
import StubCollections from 'meteor/hwillson:stub-collections';
import {sinon} from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:sinon';

// HELPERS
import {withRenderedTemplate, renderTemplate, withDiv} from '../../test-helpers.js';

// COMPONENTS
import '../../../startup/both/schemaDefaults';
import {loadingClassName} from '../../components/loading/loading';
import {Comments} from '../../../api/comments/Comments';
import '../comments.js';


describe("UI/Comments", function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        StubCollections.stub(Comments);
        Template.registerHelper('_', key => key);
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        Template.deregisterHelper('_');
        StubCollections.restore();
        Meteor.subscribe.restore();
    });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

    it("renders a loading symbol on load", function (done) {

        sinon.stub(Meteor, 'subscribe', () => ({
            subscriptionId: Random.id(),
            ready: () => false,
        }));

        withRenderedTemplate(Template.comments, {}, el => {
            const target = $(el);
            chai.assert.equal(target.find('.' + loadingClassName).length, 1);
            done();
        });

    });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    it("displays a message if no comments exist for the given document", function (done) {

        sinon.stub(Meteor, 'subscribe', () => ({
            subscriptionId: Random.id(),
            ready: () => true,
        }));

        withRenderedTemplate(Template.comments, {docId: Random.id()}, el => {
            const target = $(el);
            chai.assert.equal(target.find('.' + loadingClassName).length, 0);
            chai.assert.equal(target.find('.no-comments').length, 1);
            done();
        });

    });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    it("displays comments, if comments are found", function (done) {

        sinon.stub(Meteor, 'subscribe', () => ({
            subscriptionId: Random.id(),
            ready: () => true,
        }));

        const userId = Random.id();
        const commentDoc = {
            title: Meteor.user().username,
            status: 0,
            docId: Random.id(),
            description: "this is a comment",
            createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
            updatedAt: new Date().getTime(),
            createdBy: userId,
            updatedBy: userId,
        };

        Comments.insert(commentDoc);

        withRenderedTemplate(Template.comments, {docId: Random.id()}, el => {
            const target = $(el);
            assert.equal(target.find('.' + loadingClassName).length, 0);
            assert.equal(target.find('.no-comments').length, 0);
            assert.isAbove(target.find('.comment-entry').length, 0);
            done();
        });
    });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    it("displays a comment of self different than comments of others", function (done) {
        assert.fail("not yet implemented");
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer, myself after digging in the DOM.

This may also be interesting to non-Meteor users:

The mocha web reporter uses for the error output a css classname called `.error` which is of course very vulnerable to css overrides.

I first thought, that this could not be the issue, because I usually use prefixed classnames to avoid such conflicts.

But I installed a package with an editor, that also comes with a default css which also has an entry, called:

```
.error {
    display: none;
}
```

Meteor app wonderfully bundled all that in a way, that when running my Mocha test, the error fields got hidden in the web reporter.

I removed the editor package and my issue got solved.

What I learned from this: don't use common names for css classes in a package.